# How to set save checkbox value in android database without check all checkboxes in Android?

Tags: android, checkbox

I have 7 checkboxes, if checked each checkbox will be calculate 3 edittext based on user input (Number). if user doesn't checked, 3 edittext setEnabled(false);
so, i have a problem when execute save button, it couldn't save if all checkbox are checked. i want only selected checkboxes can do saving in sqlite db and calcuate 3 ediitext.

Here is my code,

```
p1=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cek1);
cp1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editcp1);
cp12=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editcp12);
cp13=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editcp13);

    p1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked){
                    palm1=longitude+","+latitude;
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), palm1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    percentage();

                    cp1.setEnabled(true);
                    cp1.setFocusable(true);
                    cp12.setEnabled(true);
                    cp12.setFocusable(true);
                    cp13.setEnabled(true);
                    cp13.setFocusable(true);

                     String larva1 = cp1.getText().toString().trim(); 
                     String larva12 = cp12.getText().toString().trim(); 
                     String pupa1 = cp13.getText().toString().trim(); 

                 }else{
                    palm1="-";
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), palm1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    cp1.setEnabled(false);
                    cp1.setFocusable(false);
                    cp12.setEnabled(false);
                    cp12.setFocusable(false);
                    cp13.setEnabled(false);
                    cp13.setFocusable(false);

                } }});
```

Here is handle when execute save Button

```
save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnsave);
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

    int lv1= Integer.parseInt(larva1);
    int lv12= Integer.parseInt(larva12);
    int pup1= Integer.parseInt(pupa1);

    int total=lv1+lv12+pup1;
    String totallv1=Integer.toString(ttllv1);

    upd.setpalm1(palm1);
    upd.setlarva1(larva1);
    upd.setlarva12(larva12);
    upd.setpupa1(pupa1);
    upd.settotal1(totallv1);

    db.addUPD(upd);
    db.close();
    }});
```

Then MySQLiteHelper :

```
public void addUPD(UPD upd){
Log.d("addUPD", upd.toString());
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    values.put(KEY_PALM1, upd.getpalm1());
    values.put(KEY_LARVA1, upd.getlarva1());
    values.put(KEY_LARVA12, upd.getlarva12());
    values.put(KEY_PUPA1, upd.getpupa1());
    values.put(KEY_TTL_LARVA, upd.getttl_larva());
    db.insert(TABLE_UPD, null, values); 
    db.close(); 
        }
```

Class UPD -->

```
public class UPD {
private String palm1;
private String larva1,larva12,pupa1,totallv1;

public String getpalm1(){
        return palm1;}
    public void setpalm1(String palm1) {
            this.palm1 = palm1;}

public String getlarva1(){
        return larva1;}
    public void setlarva1(String larva1) {
            this.larva1 = larva1;}

    public String getlarva12(){
        return larva12;}
    public void setlarva12(String larva12) {
            this.larva12 = larva12;}

    public String getpupa1(){
        return pupa1;}
    public void setpupa1(String pupa1) {
            this.pupa1 = pupa1;}

public String getttl_larva(){
        return ttl_larva;}
public void setttl_larva(String ttl_larva) {
        this.ttl_larva= ttl_larva;}
```

Please your advice

Comment: Sorry, sister, I cannot understand your problem. Are you need to save all checkbox states? Or you want save only selected checkboxes in database? Or something else?

Comment: only selected checkboxes @ghostman

Comment: I understood. In database it better to save all values (7 rows). Just you need to save state in database then user check some checkbox (add listener on this event) and save its value in database in its listener (no add new row in database, just update existing row).

Comment: can you give me a code ? @ghostman

Comment: Then you need to read values (select all values where state is true, and update state of only these checkboxes).

Comment: `somecheckbox. setOnCheckedChangeListener (new OnCheckedChangeListener() {  public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {//Here you need to save value in DB}});`

Comment: why on save button code, doesn't working @ghostman?

Comment: Create array that will contain your checkboxes it more easy to manage them.

Comment: Check, maybe you have error in sql request. Or post it here, and your table creation script.

Answer (score 0):

Example, table:

```
"CREATE TABLE settings (
checkId INTEGER NOT NULL,
value INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0);"
```

Code, in checkbox on checked change listener:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("value", isChecked); //checkbox value
db.update("settings", cv, "checkId LIKE ?", new String[] {checkBoxIndex});
```

Comment: could you please to help me based on my code ?? i am  a newbie in mobile application...